# Is the claim that the star Sirius does not precess like other stars true?

Tags: the-sun, binary-star, precession, equinox

There is this popular claim on Internet that the star Sirius does not precess like other stars.

The idea comes from mainly Greeks and Egyptians using Sirius to track seasons, as part of the [Sothic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sothic_cycle).

Wikipedia says that Sirius is used for the Sothic cycle because it's ~40 degrees away from the ecliptic, but there are other stars which are 40 degrees and even further away from ecliptic, why only Sirius? Why is this property only present in Sirius?.

[This](https://magneticnature.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/how-our-sun-orbits-sirius/amp/) and [this](https://humanoriginproject.com/sirius-mythology-two-sun-solar-system/) website, of questionable reputation conjectures that our Sun revolves around Sirius with the period  of 24,000 years which is approximately equal to time taken for one cycle of precession of equinoxes, therefore Sirius always staying still in the sky.

[image]

Given that the distance between Sun and Sirius is around 8 light years, 24000 years seems to be too quick a time period, but then to calculate the time period of twin star systems is complicated as the distance changes dramatically. Also there is the Centauri system which is around 4 light years away from the Sun. Can the Sun, Sirius and Centauri systems together form a bigger system which has a time period of 24000 years?

Is this model even feasible? If not, why does Sirius not precess like other stars?

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't say that.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it because the question is based on a totally wrong idea? Is it because the OP hasn't done _prior research_? I've seen other people on the internet confused about this, probably because there are many sites proposing this fantasy as accepted scientific theory. I think that it may be difficult do distinguish truth from someone without a scientific background, also because Wikipedia can be difficult to understand. Is this kind of question to be down voted in general?

Comment: @ProfRob Wikipedia does say that, please go to Sothic cycle amd go to Mechanics. It's given there.

Comment: The wikipedia page on "Sothic cycle" says that the period between heliacal risings is 365.25 days. I am not sure how you equate that to "does not undergo precession". Could you explain in the question.

Comment: @ProfRob yes I have edited it and made it clear

Comment: I'm not sure it is clearer. Now the paragraph about Sothic cycle looks unrelated to the rest of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sirius precesses like the rest of the sky.  Precession is caused by changes in the orientation of the Earth. Every star precesses as the Earth wobbles.

Sirius also has a fairly high proper motion. But not so high that it "stands still".

The precession of Sirius was the first observation of precession, as it was noted that the helical rising of Sirius and the tropical year (the year counted from vernal equinox to vernal equinox) were not synchronized, and the Heliacal rising of Sirius was coming slightly later in the season each year. This change in the day of the Heliacal rising, compared to the tropical year (which is well approximated by the Gregorian calendar) is due to the precession of Sirius.

The websites you link to are pure cloud cuckoo land fantasy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.